# impact of lombard effect on language identification

Tags: classification, r

I have collected samples for 2 different languages. Now i need to extract MFCC features and identify which language using wave files.

I need to do classification using R studio and perform an analysis on RR,EER,etc and finding out which classifier gives better results.

Can someone help me to proceed with this.

Comment: I am afraid that the question is too broad phrased in this way. It would be better if it was focused on one of the steps required to reach your goal (once you clear that, you can ask something else for the next step). Also, DSP.SE has a tag for assignments which would be good to use it if this is really some form of assignment.

Comment: As another commenter has pointed out, the scope of your question is too broad - try implementing the steps you have described and see how far you get. If you get stuck and are unsure how to proceed you can post a more detailed question including details of the input data you have available and the specific output you are expecting to achive.